# node + express + mongoose query authentification

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im building a simple web app app in express, and I'm a bit stuck in the authentification for my sessions, im going to validate everything in the client with backbone and regExp eventually when i start building the front end of the app. no basycally i have an issue with the query in mongoose returning a mongoose document object. I've looked up a couple of solutions, in the query you can use a .lean() to get an object, or grab the return from the query and apply a .toObject(), that all works fine and dandy, however when i try and authenticate the value of the key with a string it returns false. i'll post an example code, its not exactly what i've got, but its close enough to get the point across.

this would be an example of my models file

```
var User = new Schema({}, { strict: false });

User.method('authenticate', function(plainText) {
var object = this.toObject();
return plainText == object.password;  });
mongoose.model('User', User);
mongoose.connect( definitions.dbConnect );
```

and in my app file i would have something like

```
app.get('/session', routes.showLogin);
app.post('/session/new', routes.login);
```

and in my routes file id have something like

```
exports.login = function(req, res){


var userQuery = new RegExp(req.body.username , 'i');
var passwordQuery = new RegExp(req.body.password, 'i');     
var Query = User.find();

Query.findOne().where('username', userQuery).exec(function(err, user){

        if(user && user.authenticate((req.body.password))){
                    req.session.userId = user._id;

                }else{

                    res.redirect('/session');
                }
    });
},
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, its probably very silly... : /

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I would start by determining what `plainText` and `object.password` are, that might give you a clue why the function returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YEah robert klep was right on the money, After i seearched the mongoose Documentation and the mongodb docs as well, it became clear that queries return a mongo document object, in terms should be converted to the same object or variable types for opperands to work.